# Purpose of ipmitool

Tags: opensolaris, ipmi

what is the purpose of ipmitool. You can configure ipmi via the bios and it should be OS independent? I should be able to utlize all of the features of ipmi on a computer even if ipmitool is not installed and configured properly, correct? I spent a buttload of time getting BMC driver to work in opensolaris before remember that everything could have been done from the bios in a tenth of the time.

Answer (score 0):

i've used ipmitool on remote machines to power cycle and sometimes get server statistics

Comment: I meant in terms of a node, why is it necessary. 

Compute A is the central computer and B is a node. A should have ipmitool configured properly so that it can power cycle other machines, but I don't think B needs ipmi tool to receive commands?

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated perhaps "nodes" or workhorses do not need the tool, assuming master/management can access the ipmi on the nodes

Unless your are running redhat cluster services and are using ipmi fences, in which case I think you will need ipmi tool installed on each node to correctly instigate fencing.